# I get a value of 1 from the os.system(). Is it good? Has the .bat file opened correctly?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I ran the following command in python.

```
retval = os.system(..Path_to_my_exe_file); I get an retval of 1
print retval
```

Is there anyway to print the contents of the exe file open in the python code.
I am relatively new to this and would appreciate any help.

Comment: What do you mean by "the contents of the exe file"?

Comment: @ i am working on windows. I want to read the contents from the bash file and print it out in my python code.I get a retval of 1. Has the file opened correctly?

Comment: Now there's a bash file? Where'd that come from? What do you have, what do you want to do with it, and what do you want to see?

Comment: I am working on a personal project and I need some help. I want to create a python scriptwhich will query the contents of the data_values.bat and prints out query results in the following format.
Format: <task name="Training/Parameter/ENABLE_K" value="20" />

The .bat is located in another folder and the python code is located on the Desktop.

Comment: `with open('..Path_to_my_exe_file', 'r') as rf: print(rf.read())`. If I understood you correctly. If you want to read the contents of a text file why are you trying to execute it?

Comment: @I dont want to open a txt file. It is a bash file that I want to open using my python code. The bash file in windows, prints out data in the format as  <task name="Training/Parameter/ENABLE_K" value="20" />. Thats why i do a os.system() call and I get a value of 1, not sure if it is good.

Comment: great. but it is **also** a text file :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of the value which os.system() returns depends on the shell you are using. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system for more information.

Judging by the comments however, it seems that you are looking for something different.

To run a batch file in python, and to capture the output of the batch file you can use the following(From: [Piping Batch File output to a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842120/piping-batch-file-output-to-a-python-script))

```
import subprocess

output= subprocess.Popen(
    ("Path to your batch file", "an argument", "another argument"),
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout

for line in output:
    # do your work here

output.close()
```

To just read the code inside of the batch file, you can do:

```
batch_code = open("Path to your batch file",'r').read()
```